# Struggling with web chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium

I had a working selenium notebook, which I didn't use for three weeks, and now crash :-(

It seems I am not alone : 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1548

I understand that Chrome change of version, going to version 54 recently, and making old selenium's version crashing.

Following several blogs I finally downloaded webdriver again : 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

And following opera driver (yes, I also tried opera :-/ ) 
https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/blob/master/examples/desktop.py

I still had the issue.

So here is the log :

```
from selenium                  import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service

webdriver_service = service.Service('/Users/romain/anaconda/bin/chromedriver_bug')
webdriver_service.start()

driver = webdriver.Remote(webdriver_service.service_url, webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.OPERA)
```

giving :

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: bad inspector message: {"method":"Page.loadEventFired","params":{"timestamp":88165,388799}}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
```

How am I supposed to change webdriver ? I just copy-pasted the unziped file into ~/Anaconda/bin/webdriver.
Is that the correct way ?

EDIT ==================

I did :

```
$ pip install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /Users/romain/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I downloaded Chrome Driver from : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/

I unpacked the [`chromedriver_mac64 (1).zip`] and get the [`chromedriver`] file which I placed below [`~/anaconda/bin`].

I have :

```
$ which jupyter
~/anaconda/bin/jupyter
```

I did :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

And I get a blocked program, with an opened windows, and no url fetch : 
[image]

The same if I do  :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
webdriver_service = service.Service('/Users/romain/anaconda/bin/chromedriver')
webdriver_service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(webdriver_service.service_url, webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.OPERA)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

I get : 
[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of selenium stand alone server and chromedriver?

Comment: I have no clue :-/ how can I check that ?

Comment: Check http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and get the latest versions.

Comment: I did 'pip install -U selenium' would that do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at :

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1552

and set :

```
LC_NUMERIC=”en_US.UTF-8″
LANG=”en_US.UTF-8″
```

in my  ~/.bash_profile

then it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade you selenium to latest
`pip install --upgrade selenium`

Make sure you replace your older version of chromedriver with the latest version i.e unzip and paste into the same location where the earlier chromedriver was.

Comment: Seems not to be enough (I upadted my question according to your request-

Comment: Enable debug logs as suggested here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging and then post it to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=817